Per Rashi in Genesis, who were the Nefilim?
The Torah states (Genesis 6:4):
הַנְּפִלִ֞ים הָי֣וּ בָאָ֘רֶץ֮ בַּיָּמִ֣ים הָהֵם֒ וְגַ֣ם אַֽחֲרֵי־כֵ֗ן אֲשֶׁ֨ר יָבֹ֜אוּ בְּנֵ֤י הָֽאֱלֹהִים֙ אֶל־בְּנ֣וֹת הָֽאָדָ֔ם וְיָלְד֖וּ לָהֶ֑ם הֵ֧מָּה הַגִּבֹּרִ֛ים אֲשׁר מֵעוֹלָ֖ם אַנְשֵׁ֥י הַשֵּֽׁם׃ {פ}
It was then, and later too, that the Nephilim appeared on earth—when divine beings cohabited with the human women, who bore them offspring. Such were the heroes of old, the men of renown.
Rashi -
הנפלים. עַל שֵׁם שֶׁנָּפְלוּ וְהִפִּילוּ אֶת הָעוֹלָם, וּבְלָשׁוֹן עִבְרִית לְשׁוֹן עֲנָקִים הוּא: THE GIANTS — Thy were called נפילים because they fell (נפלו) and caused the downfall of (הפילו) the world (Genesis Rabbah 26:7).
Are these two different interpretations? Let's focus on the first one.
if we accept the premise that Rashi holds that these Nefilim were prior-angels who fell from heaven. (see further) several questions emerge.
Rashi Bamidbar 13:

הנפילים. עֲנָקִים, מִבְּנֵי שַׁמְחָזַאי וַעֲזָאֵל שֶׁנָּפְלוּ מִן הַשָּׁמַיִם בִּימֵי דּוֹר אֱנוֹשׁ
the giants: Heb. נְפִילִים, giants, descended from Shamhazai (Nidah 61a) and Azael (Yoma 67b), who fell (שֶׁנָּפְלוּ) from heaven in the generation of Enosh.

So Rashi in numbers is telling us that the Nefilim spotted by the spies were descendants of fallen angels. Thus, again, it may be fair to say that when Nefilim are mentioned for the very first time in Genesis without the word "sons," it is a reference to those original fallen angels.
Then Rashi in Genesis explains the next part of the verse which follows the phrase 'who bore them offspring' ("such were ... men of renown") - presumably he will 1) elaborate on how/why the offspring of the fallen angels were men of renown or 2) further identify the fallen angels as to how/why they were men of renown ... but instead:
אנשי השם. אוֹתָן שֶׁנִּקְּבוּ בְשֵׁמוֹת עִירָד מְחוּיָאֵל מְתוּשָׁאֵל שֶׁנִּקְּבוּ עַל שֵׁם אָבְדָּן, שֶׁנִּמֹּחוּ וְהֻתְּשׁוּ.אנשי שם MEN OF RENOWN (literally, men of name) — Men who bore distinctive names: עירד, מחויאל, מתושאל being so named because these names have reference to their destruction, for they were wiped out and torn out from the world (מחוי-אל would signify “wiped-out-by-God”, מתושאל “Torn-out-by-God).
quite the non-sequitur ... Rashi suddenly describes a non-fallen angel paternal set - sons of Cain.
****** these men however descended from the human - Kayin. There are no fallen angels in their genetics/DNA/paternity tests nor are these men the original fallen angels?!!**
By way of example, the Beer Basadeh rejects the Mizrachi and Nachalot Yaakov and states that per Rashi and Zohar, Nefilim here in Genesis, is a reference to the original angels cast out of heaven.

So how then did we get to a discussion regarding Cain's children?

Is rashi rejecting the premise that the genesis Nefilim were fallen angels a la his comment in numbers? Is he instead claiming that they were humans of Cain's paternal line and that they fell spiritually and caused others to fall?
Does Rashi agree the Nefilim are fallen angels but then interprets bnei elohim as a different set  - from Kain?
or could the genes of the fallen angels be manifest in Cain's line through maternal descent? There is a fascinating sforno on numbers 13:33

בני ענק. מצד האב:
בני ענק, descended paternally from giants
מן הנפילים. מצד האם: descended maternally from Nefillim

It appears to me that you have unfortunately tainted the question by assuming translations of terms (or perhaps have been misled by another's). Where we are unsure of how Rashi would translate/explain a term, we should simply transliterate it rather than insert our own translation/opinion, e.g. it would be preferable to write "'Anaqim" instead of "Giants" and "Benei-elohim" instead of "divine-beings".  And if we take a stance on how Rashi interprets a given term, then we ought demonstrate it before simply asserting it. I do not see any angels mentioned in any of the Rashis you've cited.

@Deuteronomy Rashi in Bamidbar 13 seems to me to be pretty clearly referencing the fallen angels legend

@JoelK and yet he refrains from identifying them as such.
